# How to update a record's PK which with FK point to

Tags: oracle, transactions

I have a database in Oracle like this

```
stu_choose_lesson ----> student <-----leave_apply
                          /|\
                           |
                           |
                           |-------message
```

Then, I have a homework which let me to update a record in student, and based on the requirements I can't use 'on update'.

I run these commands in sqlplus.

```
BEGIN
UPDATE student SET studentNum=200204 WHERE studentNum=200202;
UPDATE stu_choose_lesson SET studentNum=200204 WHERE studentNum=200202;
UPDATE leave_apply SET studentNum=200204 WHERE studentNum=200202;
UPDATE message SET studentNum=200204 WHERE studentNum=200202;
END;
/
```

Then I get this error.

```
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C007646) violated - child record found
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I google it and do this.

```
SET CONSTRAINTS SYS_C007647 DEFERRED;
```

But I get this error.

```
ORA-02447: cannot defer a constraint that is not deferrable
```

I know I have done some wrong things, but I don't know how to do and how to google it.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use a CTE and update that in a single statement

Comment: @AluanHaddad The homework requirements is "Use transactions to do follow update: update studentNum from '200202' to '200204', and update all FK at the same time(don't use on update)." So, I don't know does the CTE reach the requirement or not.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle will not let you update a record when there is a PK-FK relationship with another record in another table. You can follow the steps below:

1. Disable the FK constraints (which point to studentNum column in student table) in the stu_choose_lesson, leave_apply, message tables.
2. Update the records in the stu_choose_lesson, leave_apply, message tables.
3. Update the record in student table. (Note that sturent table must be the last one to be updated as it is the kone with primary key)
4. Enable the FK constraints (the ones disabled in first step) in the stu_choose_lesson, leave_apply, message tables.

The following script should work for you, just replace the constraint names with the ones in your stu_choose_lesson, leave_apply, message tables:

```
BEGIN
alter table stu_choose_lesson
DISABLE constraint
<your FK_constraint name goes here>;

alter table leave_apply
DISABLE constraint
<your FK_constraint name goes here>;

alter table message
DISABLE constraint
<your FK_constraint name goes here>;

UPDATE stu_choose_lesson SET studentNum=200204 WHERE studentNum=200202;
UPDATE leave_apply SET studentNum=200204 WHERE studentNum=200202;
UPDATE message SET studentNum=200204 WHERE studentNum=200202;
UPDATE student SET studentNum=200204 WHERE studentNum=200202;

alter table stu_choose_lesson
ENABLE constraint
<your FK_constraint name goes here>;

alter table leave_apply
ENABLE constraint
<your FK_constraint name goes here>;

alter table message
ENABLE constraint
<your FK_constraint name goes here>;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is a minimal example describing your problem

**Setup**

```
create table student (id number, name varchar2(100));
alter table student add  primary key (id);

create table student_lesson (id number, student_id number);
alter table student_lesson add  primary key (id);
alter table student_lesson add constraint
   fk_student_lesson FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
   references student (id);

-- data
insert into student (id,name) values(1,'x');
insert into student_lesson (id,student_id) values(1,1);
commit;
```

**Problem**

```
update student set id = 2 where id = 1;
-- fails with ORA-02292
```

The problem is, that the constraint in not [deferrable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1015767) an the first update invalidate the FK constraint.

**Solution 1**
Drop the contrain and define it `DEFERRABLE`

```
alter table student_lesson drop constraint fk_student_lesson;
alter table student_lesson add constraint
   fk_student_lesson FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
   references student (id) 
   initially deferred deferrable;
```

Now you can update both records (PK and FK) and the re-validation of the constraint will be *deferrend* until `COMMIT`.

```
update student set id = 2 where id = 1; 
update student_lesson set student_id = 2 where student_id = 1; 
commit
```

**Solution2**
If you can't modify the constraint, do not perform update, but `INSERT` the new *STUDENT* records, update the child table and `DELETE` the old *student* record. I.e. perform the `UPDATE` *logically* using INSERT + DELETE.

```
insert into student (id,name) values(2,'x');
update student_lesson set student_id = 2 where student_id = 1; 
delete from student where id = 1;
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "lesson" is to change the value of a primary key, your lesson is teaching you to do the wrong thing. You should NEVER change the value of a primary key - instead, a new record should be inserted and the old record should be deleted. A primary key has THREE attributes:

1. It is never NULL.
2. It is unique.
3. IT IS NEVER CHANGED.

The reason you're having the difficulties you're having is that you're violating rule #3.

DON'T DO THIS!